# "Error in parse_url(url) : length(url) == 1 is not TRUE" when I use sapply

Tags: r, api, sapply

I've created a function to call an API, but I have a problem with length(url). I simplified my code as follow to show the problem:

```
library(jsonlite)
library(httr)

df<-data.frame("names"=c("20523717759","20555589574"))
calling<- function(x){
  url1<-paste("https://api.sunat.cloud/ruc/",x,sep = "", collapse = NULL)
  url1
  res<- GET(url1)
  }

sapply(df,calling)
```

I have the next error:
`Error in parse_url(url) : length(url) == 1 is not TRUE`
The traceback is this:

```
13.
stop(simpleError(msg, call = if (p <- sys.parent(1L)) sys.call(p))) 
12.
stopifnot(length(url) == 1) 
11.
parse_url(url) 
10.
is.url(url) 
9.
stopifnot(is.url(url)) 
8.
build_url(parse_url(url)[c("scheme", "hostname", "port")]) 
7.
handle_name(url) 
6.
handle_find(url) 
5.
handle_url(handle, url, ...) 
4.
GET(url1) 
3.
FUN(X[[i]], ...) 
2.
lapply(X = X, FUN = FUN, ...) 
1.
sapply(df, calling)
```

How can I change my function "calling" to apply to my df ? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, we may need to extracting the 'names' column and then use

```
sapply(df$names, calling)
```

Comment: Thanks, guy. This run perfectly.